# Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've tried different solutions here like restarting adb..etc, none of them worked for me.
I'm getting this error:

```
    Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

    Cause:
    An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

AND this error too:

```
Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found in C:/Users/admin/Desktop/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar
```

.
    Here's the error log:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x44dfd200, pid=456, tid=8188
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x44dfd200
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

By the way i'm using Android Studio 3.0 beta2

Anybody help me please!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've had had the exact same problem and I found that even rolling back to Android 2.3 didn't help!

In the end I found that this problem only happens when running against either Java 8 update 131 or 144. If I rollback to update 121 all works fine!

Answer (score 3):

That's an error in beta version of Android Studio: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177278

As a workaround, add the following line

```
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
```

to file `~/.AndroidStudioPreview3.0/studio64.vmoptions` and relaunch Android Studio.

Comment: On 32-bit Windows, adding the line to the file `studio.exe.vmoptions` works. Thanks @Dzmitry Lazerka!